# C++, Clear the screen in Repl.it

Tags: c++, text, console, erase, replit

I'm using a website, repl.it, to program in C++. I use the site because I often use a computer that can't download the software for c++. I'm trying to make a card game that display the contents of the cards on the console. I need to be able to write and delete information on the screen. The problem is that I don't know how to remove the written text. I tried:
std::cout << "\b";
But that was kind of didn't work.
Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clearing the screen use `system("clear")`. Here is an example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Press any key to clear the screen.\n";
  std::cin.ignore();
  system("clear");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This makes everything a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. You can use ANSI escape codes. Here is a website that can explain the basics http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html It uses python but the codes are the same. To clear the screen: std::cout << "\u001b[2J"; This works on Repl.it. sanitizedUser answers works too and is way simpler. If you just want to clear the screen, I would prefer his method.